# Sort by two columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have this:

```
A    B    C
1    4    string1 
2    11   string2  
1    13   string3
2    43   string4
```

And, I want to sort by both A and B at once, to get this:

```
A    B    C
1    4    string1 
1    13   string3
2    11   string2  
2    43   string4
```

Using the following didn't do the sort

```
data =  data.sort_values(by=['A','B'], ascending=[True,True])
```

Comment: You can't set the index to a dataframe

Comment: Where are you performing a natural sort?

Comment: @SethMMorton, I actually found the column was a string and not numeric which is why the df wasn't sorting properly. I've tweaked the title and text to better relect the answer for other users. Ed

Comment: I see. You might want to remove the natural sort tag as well, then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need assign output to new `DataFrame`, parameter `ascending` can be omit, because `ascending=True` is default value in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
data = data.sort_values(by=['A','B'])
print (data)
   A   B        C
0  1   4  string1
2  1  13  string3
1  2  11  string2
3  2  43  string4
```

Comment: Also, `inplace=True` will work instead or reassigning to `data`.

Comment: @SethMMorton Thank you for comment, you are right it is another possible solution. `data.sort_values(by=['A','B'], inplace=True)` `print (data)`